# Why does syslog-ng insert logs into a table in multiple rows?

Tags: postgresql, syslog-ng

Why does syslog-ng insert logs into a table in multiple rows?

[image]

Above you can see two logs, but they are separated into six rows. Can I get syslog-ng to insert a log into one line? Should I use a trigger? I am using postgressql.

Comment: Could you share your syslog-ng configuration ? Possible an example input log ? or a way to reproduce ? Also your syslog-ng version ?

Comment: Basic configuration, postgres sends logs to the syslog then syslog to the server where it receives it syslog-ng and inserts into the table. The logs concern SELECT from a relationship that does not exist in the database. The latest version of syslog-ng.

Comment: We may have a different opinion about *basic configuration*, or databse scheme.
Anyway syslog-ng has a debug log level, where it prints out the SQL transactions, you could check if it also multiple insert (start syslog-ng with -Fde options)
(on my local setup I could not observer this behavior)